# How to update post_meta using rest-api?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to update attachment metadata using the default rest API, in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/) it says it supports the `meta` field. But when I'm trying to update the `artist` or `album` field for an audio file using `REST API`, it doesn't save the data.

Payload:

```js
{
    meta: {artist: "Mons"}
    artist: "Mons"
    title: "Hello world"
}
```

Also tried with:

```js
{
    meta: _wp_attachment_metadata: { {artist: "Mons"} }
    artist: "Mons"
    title: "Hello world"
}
```

Endpont: `/wp-json/api/v2/media/__ID__/`

Here title gets updated but artist doesn't.

Comment: Have you registered `artist` as meta field for media? Or are you using a plugin that created the `artist` meta key?